# Luabind: "No matching overload found, candidates:"

Tags: c++, lua, luabind

Note, I have read and applied the answer to: [Calling C++ member function from Luabind causes "No matching overload found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798938/calling-c-member-function-from-luabind-causes-no-matching-overload-found), but this did not solve my issue.

I have a simple class that I expose to LUA via luabind

Here is the binding code:

```
void LogManager::luaBindImpl() const
{
    using namespace luabind;
    lua_State* state(Supervisor::getSingleton().getManager<LuaManager>()->state());

    // LogManager
    module(state)
    [
        class_<LogManager>("LogManager")
        .enum_("LogType")
        [
             value("Info", 1)
            ,value("Warning", 2)
            ,value("Critical", 3)
            ,value("Debug", 4)
        ]
        .def("log", &LogManager::log)
        .def("registerSource", &LogManager::registerSource)
    ];

    // Add to globals
    globals(state)["LogManager"] = this;
};  // eo luaBindImpl
```

And here is my LUA:

```
LogManager.registerSource("lol");
```

But I get the error mentioned in the title (this taken straight from my log file):

```
00:00:00:0520- lua:Exception - No matching overload found, candidates:
void registerSource(LogManager&,std::string const&)
```

I've been tearing my hair out over this and can't see what I am doing wrong.  Can anyone shed any light?! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Lua part, you need to use colon (`:`) instead of a dot:

```
LogManager:registerSource("lol");
```

And you do realize the global variable `LogManager` has the same name with the class `LogManager`; that way you won't be able to use the enum constants, e.g. `LogManager.Info` will return nil.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I modified the global to `LM`, and changed it so it was `LM:registerSource("lol");`, but I still get the same error.

Comment: @Moo-Juice: well, I have no more ideas. I managed to recreate your problem exactly, using `:` fixed it. What I can suggest is to build luabind with debug info, set a breakpoint in function::call (that should be in function.cpp, around line 50) and just examine the Lua stack and how luabind looks for overloads.

Comment: @sbk, it's got a little bit more interesting.  Apparently i don't have `tostring` or `require`, either.  I get `[string "local tostring = tostring..."]:6: attempt to call local 'tostring' (a nil value)`.  I thought that was built-in?  Most confused.... :)

Comment: Hardly anything is built-in in Lua - to "import" standard functions in your environment you must call some `luaopen_XXX` functions from `lualib.h` (for example `luaopen_io()` for the io stuff, `luaopen_base` for `tostring` and such) or call `luaL_openlibs` to import everything

Comment: @sbk, hi there.  Yes, you are quite right.  Adding those sorted all of that stuff out.  Interestingly, `globals(state)["LM"] = new LogManager()` works as intended.  It just appears assigning `this` fails...

Comment: @Moo-Juice: Now that you mentioned assigning `this` fails, but `new LogManager` is OK, I have a new guess: your `luaBindImpl` method is const, hence `this` is `const LogManager` and I can see how that can confuse things. Try making `luaBindImpl` not const, or cast the const away from `this` when assigning the global...

Comment: @Moo-Juice: hehe, I just saw you asked the same question in the luabind-user mail list and got pretty much the same reply, so I'd guess that will be the final solution to that particular problem :)

Comment: This was indeed the case!  Everything is going swimmingly now, thank-you for your continued efforts :)