# luabind - No matching overload found, candidates

Tags: c++, luabind

So this trouble been confusing me for many days.
I didn't leave a proposed solution, but non worked.
To simplify the problem, in luabind I try to export a class which has a function which returns an object from another class, like this example:

```
class A
{
public:
    int x;
};
class B
{
    A m_a;
public:
    A* getA(){return &m_a;} // I am curious about this function
}*g_b=new B();
```

and the exported module:

```
void ExportToLua(lua_State* L)
{
    module(L)[
        class_<A>("A")
            .def(constructor<>())
            .def_readwrite("x",&A::x)
            ,
        class_<B>("B")
            .def(constructor<>())
            .def("getA",(A*(B::*)())&B::getA)
    ];
    luabind::globals(L)["g_B"]=boost::ref(g_b);
}
```

Simple and clear, now when I call lua script as follows:

xa=g_B:getA()

print(tostring(xa.x))

I get the following error:

No matching overload found, candidates:
A* getA(B&)

I have tried to patch typeid.hpp as proposed in:
[Calling C++ member function from Luabind causes "No matching overload found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798938/calling-c-member-function-from-luabind-causes-no-matching-overload-found)
but didn't solve my problem.

Comment: The issue seemed to be with boost, I have solved it by upgrading to the latest boost libraries...